# How to gather relative articles depends on the title in Django Python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-requests

I'm building a news website.In news detail page,I want to fetch out(gather) the relative news depend on the news title.

I only want to gather all the news that  have 3 or 4 same words in the title,and it doesn't matter what words are they.

For example,if some of the news title have the 3 same words"python AI future",and these news will be relative news to each other.

Any friend could help?

Here is my Model:

```
class News(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='标题')
```

Here is my newsDetail view:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):

    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'news': news,
    })
```

Comment: Basically, you want to gather all the news that have some particular words? in your example, you want to filter news that has "AI or Python or Future'

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Actually I only want to gather all the news that  have 3 or 4 same words in the title,and it doesn't matter what words are they.

Comment: At first glance, I thought you wanted to filter `News` that contains at least 3 or 4 words from a user's search, but I think I was wrong. Once you bring them together, how will you save this gathering for future use? will you use the algorithm (which you don't have yet) for each use? One approach is to use `category` or `tag` in your model News.

Comment: Yes,I have added tags,but I find some news website,their relatives news are all have a lot of same words in the title.I think this is a good idea that,if python can help me fetch out the news that have 4 same words in the title automatically,I will save a lot of work.So I want to find out a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a slightly different approach. I would add a tag:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then you can add that tag to your News item:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
```

Then search for related by the tag.

If you want to do it automatically from titles, you can try to parse tags from titles when you save a news item.

This has some advantages:

- if the title doesn't have a key concept, you can add that as a tag
- if the title has a keyword that is somehow not relevant, you can remove that tag
- it scales better than a full title comparison

If you're going to try to match titles, I'd recommend having a look at the Natural Language Toolkit: https://www.nltk.org/py-modindex.html

I've only used this for fun, and not in any deep or meaningful way, but it should help you do things like categorize and tag things based on the contents.

Comment: Yes,sir!Thank you for your reply.I have added tags,but I find some news website,their relatives news are all have a lot of same words in the title.I think this is a good idea that,if python can help me fetch out the news that have 4 same words in the title automatically,I will save a lot of work.So I want to find out a way to achieve it.